# Find by id in another entity grails GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have 2 entities in grails mapping

Product and Asset

I need get the asset with product id equals x and assettype equals y

I tried

```
Asset.findByProductIdAndAssetType(productId, assetType)
```

but doesn´t work

The unique solution is

Load product by id and find by product loaded

```
def product = Product.findById(productId)
Asset.findByProductAndAssetType(product, assetType)
```

Is there any way to load Asset just with productId?

Comment: `Asset.where{product.id==productId && assetType==aType}?.find()` or `Asset.find{product.id==productId && assetType==aType}`

Answer (score 8):

Use the `load` method to do this with one database call:

```
Asset.findByProductAndAssetType(Product.load(productId), assetType)
```

`load()` is similar to `get()` in that it retrieves a single instance by its id, but `load()` retrieves the instance lazily, only after you access any persistent property other than the id. `get()` immediately makes a database query and returns the instance or `null` if not found, but `load()` always returns a non-null proxy, and when it does make the database query it will populate its properties from the retrieved data if found, or throw an exception if not.

But in the solution above there's no database call for a `Product` instance since all that's needed to retrieve the `Asset` is the id to use as a foreign key.